# Как использовать Media Player в Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, mediaplayer, visual-studio-2022

В документации просто указан код для запуска плеера:

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
System.Uri manifestUri = new Uri("http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/49b57c87-f5f3-48b3-ba22-c55cfdffa9cb/Sintel.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)");
mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(manifestUri);
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Ума мне хватило его копировать и вставить, но вот MediaPlayer не обнаружен. Предлагает IDE сделать импорт System.Windows.Media. Выбираю этот пункт, но импорт не произошел. Пробую сам прописать using System.Windows.Media, но такого не находит.

В форме в панели элементов добавил элемент MediaPlayer, но в списке он не появился. Появляется только если отобразить все элементы, тогда он появится и будет серым (неактивным).

Я только начал Visual Studio осваивать и пока в полной растерянности от происходящего.
В NuGet смотрел, MediaPlayer нет, нигде в интернете не нашел как его подключать, везде уже чисто код пишут и максимум как в панель элементов добавить элемент MediaPlayer.

При установке Visual Studio 2022 выбирал только пакет с разработкой с Windows Form для винды. Платформа .NET 6.0. Целевая ОС Windows 7, сам тоже на ней.